# Pause Thread and resume it from where it stopped

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to Threads. I have a GUI with a button that starts a thread executing core operations; I've got another button which should pause the main thread when pressed.

Is it possible to resume the main thread from where it stopped?
The core of the question is **from where** the thread resumes, so it is not a duplicate question.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use wait and notify primitives.

Comment: Does it start from the beginning or from where it left?

Comment: These are things that you should learn from a good book or tutorial. There is no supported way to **pause** a thread (`Thread.suspend()` exists but should never be used and might get removed in the future), the only methods are `wait()` and `notify()` that a thread itself can use to wait for something, and abstractions build on that. Naturally, when the thread resumes, it does so from the point it waited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to manipulate threads.

`suspend()`: puts a thread in a *suspended state* and can be resumed using `resume()`

`stop()`: stops a thread

`resume()`: resumes a thread, which was suspended using `suspend()`.

`notify()`: Wakes up a single thread.

`wait()`:  makes the current thread wait.. (or sleep) until another thread invokes the `notify()` method for that thread.

`notifyAll()`:  will wake up **all** sleeping (waiting) threads.

#### Note

In the latest versions of Java resume( ), suspend( ) and stop( ) has been deprecated

#### Question from OP

*but when I wake it up, it resumes from where? Does it start from the beginning or from where it left?*

Imagine a simple `for`-loop.

```
Starting thread 1.
Starting thread 2.
Thread 1: 0
Thread 2: 0
Thread 1: 1
Thread 2: 1
Pausing thread 1.
Thread 2: 2
Thread 2: 3
Thread 2: 4
Resuming thread 1.
Thread 1: 2
Thread 2: 5
```

Comment: Ok thank you, but when I wake it up, it resumes from where? Does it start from the beginning or from where it left?

Comment: @sirdan it resumes where it was. Added example in answer.

Comment: You should **never** use `suspend()`, `stop()` or `resume()`. They have been deprecated in Java 1.2 as it is prone to deadlock or corruption/inconsistent state. See also [Why are Thread.stop, Thread.suspend and Thread.resume Deprecated?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

Comment: You're answering a question from - what looks like - a beginner, and your answer starts with the suggestion that you can use `suspend()`, `stop()` and `resume()`. My comment is to indicate that is a bad idea (since Java 1.2 (1998), so not just 'latest versions') and it is not just deprecated, but actively discouraged by the Java documentation because it can be extremely harmful to use.